# Saving the content of a div tag into an image file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I to save to content of a `<div id="container"></div>` as an image file, please?

**EDIT :** This page contains a jQuery script making the containt of that tag displaying charts. I'm trying here to save the generated containt into an image file to after include it into another web page.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: You mean converting text to image..?

Comment: @user3319426 please some examples or more details, we can't help you because we don't understand what you want..

Answer (score 0):

Check out **[html2canvas - Screenshots with JavaScript](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)**

You can also use:

```
var c = document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id');
var t = c.getContext('2d');
/* then use the canvas 2D drawing functions to add text, etc. for the result */
```

and then open a new tab with snapshot using:

```
window.open('', document.getElementById('the_canvas_element_id').toDataURL());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but, how to save it into a local file, please?